# ReactJS validate JSON Object with JSON Schema

Tags: json, reactjs, npm

In my ReactJS app, I want to validate a JSON object coming from API. I have the valid JSON schema and I want to make sure the coming object is in the correct structure before passing it.

Is there any React plugin which I can use for this.

Comment: I don't think this is a `react` specific problem. You could maybe remove the reactjs tag? There are plenty of npm packages out there which validate json schema. Like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

Answer (score -1):

If you want to draw the UI based on the json object after schema validation, then react-json-schema-form is your friend